# How can I run Visual Basic code in a running Visual Basic 6.0 process (e.g. MSVBVM60.DLL)?

Tags: c++, vb6

I'm working on debugging a legacy Visual Basic 6.0 application; the application was built into native code, but unfortunately we just have the binaries, but no source code. So I'm rather limited as far as modifications to the program go.

My final goal is to get the value of the 'Name' property of some controls given their HWND. I can easily write VisualBasic code to do this, but unfortunately I don't see how to execute this code in the context of the running application.

My first attempt was to create an ActiveX DLL in VisualBasic which exposes my 'controlNameForHWND' function. At runtime, I then had a little utility injected a second helper DLL into the VB running process, and that helper DLL then called [CoCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615(VS.85).aspx) so that my ActiveX control (which features the 'controlNameForHWND' function I wrote in VB) is instantiated inside the process of the application.

This worked well, but unfortunately the ActiveX control is apparently not executed in the same context as the application to be debugged. For instance, the global `App.hInstance` value is different, the array returned by the global `Forms` array is always empty, and so on. So all my VisualBasic script code is running in a parallel universe. Bad luck. :-/

Does anybody else have ideas how to be able to "inject" VisualBasic code into a VB6 process? Looking at the process using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) shows that the library `MSVBVM60.DLL` is loaded (the Microsoft Visual Basic Virtual Machine), but not e.g. `VBA.DLL`. The latter would be interesting since it exports an undocumented `EbExecuteLine` function to execute script statements.

I'm running a bit low on ideas, so I'm grateful for the craziest ideas, too. :-)

Comment: What is your actual goal? Surely not to get the `Name` property, surely you need to change the behaviour of the app in some way. Can you briefly describe the problem and the solution you have in mind

Comment: @Anonymous close voter, I disagree this question is "too localized". And please don't vote to close without a comment.

Comment: @MarkJ: In fact, I'm really just trying to read the value of the `Name` property for a `Control` which is idenfied by it's `hWnd`. This is part of a simplistic GUI automation system which repeats user actions to trigger a bug. In order to identify controls reliably, we would like to use the internal name of the controls. The same approach is done by GUI testing tools like e.g. WinRunner (unfortunately I don't know how they did it).

Comment: Have you looked at free GUI automation tools like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)? Maybe it can do what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VB6 ActiveX DLL *will* run in the client process, but it won't have access to the `Forms` collection of the client process. I think the `App.hInstance` should return the same value though.

If you are debugging your DLL in the VB6 IDE debugger, that *will* cause it to run in a separate process. That debugger does some crazy things. You might be better to build a PDB file from the ActiveX DLL and debug in the Visual C++ debugger.

Comment: +1 you really won't be able to do what you after AND debug it in the VB6 IDE. You're pretty much restricted to the good ol Log file and msgbox form of debugging for this kind of thing.